# Customize Windows keyboard layout

Tags: windows, keyboard-layout, non-admin

First a tiny bit of background: I customized my father's OS X keyboard layout to add him a few specific characters (specific to Polish) on his regular azerty layout.  On OSX you can do this by creating / modification an XML file which you then place at a specific spot somewhere in the user's directories. This is all working very well. And it's important because this can be done without needing the "root" password, it can be done on a per-user basis.

It is working flawlessly seen more than one year.

Now I need to do the same on Windows and hence my question. I know next to nothing about Windows so I would need very detailed steps as to how I could do that.

And first I need to know if this can be done without needing to be "admin" on Windows?

Then, how should I go about it? Is auto-hot-key (AHK) the way to go? If so can AHK itself be installed without being root? And how would I then configure it?  And where can I "find" the characters? (can I copy/paste them from a website into AHK somehow?)

It looks like a lot of questions but it's really just one simple question:

How can I customize a Windows keyboard layout to add a few characters to an AZERTY layout without being admin?

It's basically the equivalent of the following SuperUser question (3 upvotes and two favorites), but this time for Windows:

[Customize Mac OS X Keyboard Layout](https://superuser.com/questions/48461/customize-mac-os-x-keyboard-layout)

Comment: The only way to customize a keyboard layout that I know of is this rather simple tool: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/goglobal/bb964665.aspx ... Now, does it require administrator rights? Try it and you'll see. I don't know. I do know that once installed (whether it requires administrator rights or not) the layout will become just a normal layout and will be able to be selected, or not, on a per-user basis. PS: Eeew, AZERTY. Yes, yes, very useful post-scriptum.